# Permission error when using Boto3, but works via aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-cli

I'm stuck on a missing permissions issue trying to create a Lambda function.

The execution role I've configured has the following permissions:

```
$ aws --output=text iam get-role-policy --policy-name=MyRolePolicy --role-name=my-role
<snip>
POLICYDOCUMENT  2012-10-17
STATEMENT   Allow
ACTION  s3:Get*
ACTION  s3:List*
ACTION  logs:CreateLogGroup
ACTION  logs:CreateLogStream
ACTION  logs:PutLogEvents
ACTION  ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
ACTION  ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
ACTION  ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
```

And when I create a Lambda function with that role, creation succeeds:

```
$ aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name=my-test --runtime=java8 \
  --role='arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-role' \
  --handler=MyHandler \
  --code=S3Bucket=my-bucket,S3Key=app.zip
<result successful>
```

However, when I create the function using the same arguments (esp. the same execution role) I get the following error:

*Boto3 Usage*

```
client.create_function(
  FunctionName=function_name,
  Runtime='java8',
  Role=getenv('execution_role_arn'),
  Handler='MyHandler',
  Code={
    "S3Bucket": bucket,
    "S3Key": artifact_name
  },
  Publish=True,
  VpcConfig={
    'SubnetIds': getenv('vpc_subnet_ids').split(','),
    'SecurityGroupIds': getenv('vpc_security_group_ids').split(',')
  }
)
```

*Boto3 Result*

```
{
   'Error':{
      'Message':'The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface on EC2',
      'Code':'InvalidParameterValueException'
   },
   'ResponseMetadata':{
      'RequestId':'47b6640a-f3fe-4550-8ac3-38cfb2842461',
      'HTTPStatusCode':400,
      'HTTPHeaders':{
         'date':'Wed, 24 Jul 2019 10:55:44 GMT',
         'content-type':'application/json',
         'content-length':'119',
         'connection':'keep-alive',
         'x-amzn-requestid':'47b6640a-f3fe-4550-8ac3-38cfb2842461',
         'x-amzn-errortype':'InvalidParameterValueException'
      },
      'RetryAttempts':0
   }
}
```

Creating a function via the console with this execution role works as well, so I must be missing something in how I'm using Boto3, but I'm at a loss to explain.

Hopefully someone can catch a misapplication of Boto3 here, cause I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boto3 code is specifying a VPC:

```py
  VpcConfig={
    'SubnetIds': getenv('vpc_subnet_ids').split(','),
    'SecurityGroupIds': getenv('vpc_security_group_ids').split(',')
```

However, the CLI version is *not* specifying a VPC.

Therefore, the two requests are *not* identical. That's why one works and the other does not work.

From [Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Resources in an Amazon VPC - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html):

> To connect to a VPC, your function's execution role must have the following permissions.
>
> - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
> - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
> - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
>
> These permissions are included in the `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` managed policy.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the role definition to use the managed policy you mention.  I had defined the same actions (including the 3 ec2 permissions mentioned above) as the managed policy, but it only works when I had them attached to the role via the managed policy.  While I'm not clear why the role I had didn't work, I can live with this as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda has a role that allows `ec2:CreateNetworkInterface` and not the account executing script.

The current role assigned to lambda function allows for the lambda to create `VpcConfig`.

Check that the account running the script to provision the lambda is allowed the `ec2:CreateNetworkInterface` action.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It's the same account being used for running the python script as well as the call to "aws lambda create-function" and is an Admin account (i.e. "Actions *").  Besides the error message is pretty clear:  "The provided execution role does not have permissions to call CreateNetworkInterface" -- which clearly indicates that the issue is with the provided execution role, not the calling account.